# Why are my GUI Buttons Triggering upon starting the game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have been working on a GUI menu for my game, I followed instructions from various sources and got it working with the instructions from the unity website, i'm not sure if I some of my code is incorrect or if it's a bug in the game engine, but when I hit play the buttons trigger  the code attached to them without clicking on them:

```
#pragma strict

var guiSkin : GUISkin;
private var Options : boolean;
var OptionsGUI : GameObject;
var MenuGUI : GameObject;

function Start ()
{

}
function OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box(Rect(200, 360, 400, 75)," ");
    GUI.skin = guiSkin;
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 135, 400, 75),"P L A Y");
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 210, 400, 75),"O P T I O N S");
    {
        SetOptions();
    }
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 285, 400, 75),"I N S T R U C T I O N S");
    GUI.Button(Rect(200, 360, 400, 75),"A B O U T");
}
function SetOptions ()
{   
    OptionsGUI.GetComponent(options).enabled = true;
    MenuGUI.GetComponent(menu).enabled = false;
}
```

Someone told me there was C# in there but i have not used any C# in the project, if there is can you specify where it is?

Comment: What is this language? Doesn't look like normal JavaScript. Is this UnityScript or something?

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript at all and judging by that and the mention of C#, I would say you're using Unity. If so, please, tag your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about your GUI.Button "O P T I O N S", the problem is: you need to use a "If" statement, because the code below will be executed always:

```
GUI.Button(Rect(200, 210, 400, 75),"O P T I O N S");
{
    SetOptions();
}
```

The right way to do this is:

```
if(GUI.Button(Rect(200, 210, 400, 75),"O P T I O N S"))
{
   SetOptions();
}
```